# Image in background of <ul> list, css

Tags: html, css

here is my code:

```
    #jackpots {
    position: relative;
    width: 228px;
    min-height: 30px;
    background: url(images/pattern.png) repeat;
    }

    .bottomImage {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; 
    z-index: 1;
    }

    #jackpots ul {
    z-index: 2;
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="jackpots>
        <ul>
            <li>...</li>
            <li>...</li>
            <li>...</li>
            <li>...</li>
        </ul>
    <img src"some.jpg" class="bottomImage">
    </div>
```

The problem is: li elements are clickable only if there is no image under them.
I've tried with bigger z-index numbers in case there is already 1 or 2 in my entire code, no luck.

Comment: remove z-index and try? why you set it to 2?

Comment: wanted <ul> to be on top of the image. removing z-indexes doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your CSS:

```
#jackpots ul {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Changing the `position` value to `relative` will allow the `z-index` to affect the stacking order, which is what you want.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Remember to accept the answer and collect 2 reputation points.  Thank you for taking the time to post your HTML/CSS.